# AudioKit OscillatorBank Instruments?

Tags: audiokit

I'm using AudioKit(which is awesome) and having a challenge finding a best practice for building a bunch of "instruments" can be triggered from the 3d controls in my app.

When I use

```
var oscillator = AKOscillatorBank()
```

as the base for sounds I can trigger individual notes on with

```
oscillator.play(noteNumber: ...)
```

and off with

```
oscillator.stop(noteNumber: ...)
```

Now I can have multiple tones playing within one instrument.

I then found the "string" and other classes in the Playgrounds such as,

```
var pluckedString = AKPluckedString()
```

which are awesome tonally but they are not Midi instruments, so they don't come with the handy .stop(noteNumber:) method, so while I can start multiple notes on the string, I can't stop them.

Is the solution to build my own "instrument" with an array of multiple AKPluckedStrings(), or is there something else built in accomplishing something similar already that I'm not finding?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you could follow the oscillator bank model to make a bank of plucked strings.  I believe AKMandolin is set up like this too, for another example.

Comment: Cool, glad it did, consider upvoting/accepting my answer :)